# Trouble with Drupal 8 REST API and JavaScript client

Tags: 8

I have created a Drupal 8 site and enabled REST on it. I can successfully preform requests against it using Postman or curl. However, when trying to perform those requests from a JavaScript application, I receive a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error.

How do I configure Drupal to allow these requests?

Edit:

I ended up switching from Nginx to Apache for my server and following [this](https://awesometoast.com/cors/) guide for enabling CORS in Apache

Enabling CORS in Nginx should be possible, but I could not get it to work.

Comment: If it's just for developement I start chromium without web security enabled.

Comment: @dibs, thanks. I ended up moving from an Nginx server to an Apache server, and enabling CORS in Apache. I will edit my question to show what I did.